# How to round Decimal number without using the global context?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

Using python 3.6
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html

I can see we can specify the rounding and precision but it's only globally by setting the context.

How can I do this for a specific Decimal instance?

Something like this pseudo code:

```
myNumber = Decimal(1.101901)
roundedNumber = myNumber.toFixed(2, ROUND_DOWN)
# expected result ==> 1.10
roundedNumber = myNumber.toFixed(2, ROUND_UP)
# expected result ==> 1.11
```

So I can parse each number with the rounding and precision I want.

Comment: For me is not clear the expected output. Can you clarify?

Comment: I expect this Decimal to be parsed with a specific precision and a specific rounding option. I edited the question

Comment: You could use the [quantize](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) method

Comment: I would have to test it but I'm pretty sure quantize is the right answer for my problem, thanks for pointing that to me. Please post this as the right answer.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't be feeding `float` objects directly into a `Decimal`, if you can.

Comment: what should be put inside Decimal then ? what would be the drawback of doing this ?

Comment: Example code using `quantize` as suggested by @snakecharmerb:

myNumber = Decimal(1.101901)
print(myNumber.quantize(Decimal('1.00'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN))
print(myNumber.quantize(Decimal('1.00'), rounding=ROUND_UP))

Comment: yes I figured that out, so the right way to feed Decimal is string I guess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method [Decimal.quantize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize).

```
from decimal import *

myNumber = Decimal(1.101901)
roundedNumber = myNumber.quantize(Decimal('1.00'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN) # 1.10
roundedNumber = myNumber.quantize(Decimal('1.00'), rounding=ROUND_UP)   # 1.11
```